# Bind UITextField to view model variable

Tags: ios, swift, swiftbond

I'm trying to use Bond to bind UI elements to my view model. When I try to bind the searchTextField to my view models searchString, Xcode 8.3.3 gives me an "Incorrect argument label in call (have 'to:', expected 'signal:')" error. What is wrong?

```
import UIKit
import Bond
import ReactiveKit

class SearchViewModel {
   let searchString = Observable<String>("")
}

class SearchViewController: UIViewController {

   @IBOutlet weak var searchTextField: UITextField!

   let viewModel = SearchViewModel()

   override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      bindToViewModel()
   }

   func bindToViewModel() {
      searchTextField.reactive.text.bind(to: viewModel.searchString)
   }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using signal: instead of to: in the function call inside bindToViewModel?

Comment: I tried also using signal, but that gives: "Cannot convert value of type 'Property<String>' to expected argument type 'Signal<String?, NoError>' (aka 'Signal<Optional<String>, NoError>')" I'm trying to bind it exactly as it is shown in Bond:s README!?

Comment: I changed let searchString = Observable<String>("") to let searchString = Observable<String?>("") and then it works but I don't understand why it has to be an optional.

Comment: I havent worked much on this but I think it is because of this extension extension UITextField: BindableProtocol {

  public func bind(signal: Signal<String?, NoError>) -> Disposable {
    return reactive.text.bind(signal: signal)
  }
} , in UITextField.swift , where it is expecting an optional string , obviously you can further explore

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that:

```
let searchString = Observable<String>("")
```

needs to be:

```
let searchString = Observable<String?>("")
```

because `UITextField: BindableProtocol { public func bind(signal: Signal<String?, NoError>) -> Disposable { return reactive.text.bind(signal: signal) } }` expects an optional as 3stud1ant3 pointed out.